# Variadic template qualifiers

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, variadic-templates, variadic-functions

I have a templated interface with a variable number of parameters:

```
template <typename... Args>
class Base {
public:
    virtual void f(Args...) = 0;
};
```

Then I inherit another class from it:

```
class Derived : public Base<std::string, int, float> {
public:
    void f(std::string, int, float) override {}
};
```

Here I would like to pass a string(or other large object) by a constant reference. I understand that I can do this:

```
template <typename... Args>
class Base {
public:
    virtual void f(const Args&...) = 0;
};

class Derived : public Base<std::string, int, float> {
public:
    void f(const std::string&, const int&, const float&) override {}
};
```

But then the primitive types must also be passed by reference.
Can I achieve something similar?

```
class Derived : public Base<std::string, int, float> {
public:
    void f(const std::string&, int, float) override {}
};
```

Comment: It looks like you are over-engineering it, taking them by reference is probably fine. This obviously depends on the context, but make sure that complexity is actually necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this? Adjust the condition as needed.

```
template <typename... Args>
class Base {
public:
    virtual void f(std::conditional_t<std::is_scalar_v<Args>, Args, const Args&>...) = 0;
};
```

---

Though I agree with @asynts. If it was my code, I'd pass by const reference unconditionally.

Comment: hmm, I get error: `Error C3668 'Derived::f': method with override specifier 'override' did not override any base class methods`

Comment: @Egor Works for me: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/6bY9f1aac

Comment: Do I need c++20?

Comment: @Egor `std::is_scalar_v` requires c++17 and `std::conditional_t` requires c++14, but you can replace them by `std::is_scalar<T>::value` and `typename std::conditional<T>::type` to use it with c++11.

Comment: It looks like the msvc compiler can't compile it

Comment: @Egor So we found a compiler bug, huh.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Probably agree with @asynts