# Variadic template parameter pack expansion looses qualifier

Tags: c++, gcc, variadic-templates, variadic-functions

Let's say I have a variadic function template taking a function pointer to a function with said variadic arguments. The following code does not compile under gcc (11.2), but compiles under clang and msvc (https://godbolt.org/z/TWbEKWb9f).

```
#include <type_traits>

void dummyFunc(const int);

template<typename... Args>
void callFunc(void(*)(Args...), Args&&...); // <- this one is problematic
// see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67081700/variadic-template-qualifiers
template<typename... Args>
void callFunc2(void(*)(std::conditional_t<std::is_const_v<Args>, const Args, Args>...), Args&&...); // <- this one works


int main()
{
    // fails on gcc, works on clang and msvc
    callFunc<const int>(&dummyFunc, 2);
    // this works
    //callFunc(&dummyFunc, 2);
    // this works as well
    //callFunc2<const int>(&dummyFunc, 2);
}
```

Specifying the function arguments 'Args...' explicitly as 'const int' prevents gcc from compiling the code. Apparently the template parameter expansion looses the cv-qualifier under gcc, while it is kept under clang and msvc. The error message is:

```
<source>: In function 'int main()':
<source>:15:24: error: no matching function for call to 'callFunc<const int>(void (*)(int), int)'
   15 |     callFunc<const int>(&dummyFunc, 2);
      |     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
<source>:6:6: note: candidate: 'template<class ... Args> void callFunc(void (*)(Args ...), Args&& ...)'
    6 | void callFunc(void(*)(Args...), Args&&...);
      |      ^~~~~~~~
<source>:6:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
<source>:15:24: note:   types 'const int' and 'int' have incompatible cv-qualifiers
   15 |     callFunc<const int>(&dummyFunc, 2);
      |     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I found the 'solution' by utilizing type traits to make it compile here ([Variadic template qualifiers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67081700/variadic-template-qualifiers)), but I either should have to use this method or not, independently of the compiler. I know I don't have to specify the template arguments explicitly, but I want to understand why gcc fails to compile the code. Which compiler is "right", i.e. should this code compile or not (that is, should the cv-qualifier be dropped)?

As a side note, if I use a const reference instead, it compiles also under gcc, and the template argument is correctly recognized as 'const int&' (because the compiler absolutely has to do so). I am aware of the fact that, if the template argument is deduced by the compiler and not explicitly specified, that the cv-qualifier is dropped. But in my opinion gcc's behavior here is wrong because I explicitly stated the type to use. However, I don't know the standard well enough to tell whether gcc or the other two compilers are not following the standard. It seems to be related to variadic templates and not the template deduction itself, because the version without variadic templates works under gcc (https://godbolt.org/z/qn8a5bh5E):

```
void dummyFunc(const int);

template<typename Arg>
void callFunc(void(*)(Arg), Arg&&);

int main()
{
    callFunc<const int>(dummyFunc, 2);
}
```

Also, why is automatic template type deduction even working in the first (problematic) case? 'Args...' should be deduced as both 'const int', because of the function pointer, as well as 'int' because of the second argument. My guess is that in this case, 'Args...' is deduced as 'const int' (otherwise it would not compile). Is my guess correct? It would be great if somebody could hint me to the relevant section in the standard.

Comment: Top-level constness of the parameters might not be a part of the function type, I think? If I do `void dummyFunc(int);` instead, nothing changes (GCC errors out, Clang & MSVC accept the code). I think GCC strips function parameter qualifiers not in the template, but in the `dummyFunc` declaration (and fails to do so in the template, unlike the other two compilers).

Comment: All three compilers accept the code if I use `callFunc<int>(&dummyFunc, 2);`. Since GCC handles parameter packs and non-packs differently, I think it's a GCC bug. Consider reporting it.

Comment: Thank you for you valuable input. After some testing I found out that cv-qualifiers don't seem to matter for function pointers. Apparently it is okay to have a function pointer like `void (*funcPtr)(int)` pointing to either a function like `void func(int)` as well as `void func(const int)`. It is also okay to have a function pointer like `void (*funcPtr)(const int)` pointing to either a function like `void func(int)` as well as `void func(const int)`. This explains why the code from the first case compiles, as the argument can be safely deduced as int as well as const int.

Comment: I am thinking of reporting this behavior to the gcc developers, but I thought it's a good idea to ask here first in case I am missing something. I skimmed through the standard, but the only thing I found which sounds like it is related was in section 13.10.3.1, where it states: `f<int>(1) and f<const int>(1) call distinct functions even though both of the functions called have the same function type.` I believe this also applies to variadic templates and thus the code should compile, so this would indicate a bug in gcc. But I am not sure, the standard is not easy to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cv-qualifier should always be dropped (both in determining the type of `dummyFunc` and when substituting the deduced argument into the `callFunc` signature), and I'm pretty sure all compilers agree on this. It's not really what the question is about. Let's change the example a bit:

```
template <class... Args> struct S {
    template <class... T> S(T...) {}
};

template<typename... Args>
void callFunc2(S<Args...>);

int main()
{
    callFunc2<const int>(S<int>{});
}
```

Now [GCC and Clang reject the code while MSVC accepts it](https://godbolt.org/z/zfof9hcoY).

GCC and Clang both have issues with the mismatch between `const int` (explicitly specified) and `int` (deduced) whereas MSVC is evidently happy just to let `Args` = [`const int`] as specified. Who is right?

As I see it the problem here is [[temp.arg.explicit]/9](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.fct.spec#temp.arg.explicit-9), which states:

> Template argument deduction can extend the sequence of template arguments corresponding to a template parameter pack, even when the sequence contains explicitly specified template arguments.

Thus, specifying an explicit template argument for the pack `Args` does not prevent deduction. The compiler still has to try to deduce `Args` in case it needs to be extended in order to match the function parameter types against the argument types.

It has never been clearly explained what this paragraph of the standard really means. I guess MSVC's approach could possibly be something like "deduce the pack as if there were no explicitly specified template arguments, then throw out the result if the explicitly specified template arguments are not a prefix of the deduced template arguments" which seems like a sensible way to handle this code. GCC and Clang might be something like "deduce the pack as if there were no explicitly specified template arguments, and then fail if the explicitly specified template arguments are not a prefix of the deduced template arguments" which would lead to the code being ill-formed, but this seems like an unfortunate interpretation because it's inconsistent with how explicitly specified template arguments are treated in non-variadic cases.

The example above is similar to a simplified version of the OP's example:

```
void dummyFunc(int);

template<typename... Args>
void callFunc(void(*)(Args...));

int main()
{
    callFunc<const int>(&dummyFunc);
}
```

Here, the trailing `Args&&...` has been removed, which doesn't change the result: as with OP's code, [Clang and MSVC accept it while GCC doesn't.](https://godbolt.org/z/rnYbv49hx). Only Clang has changed its opinion: it accepts this one while rejecting the one with `S`. To be fair, these two snippets are not really analogous: the one with `S` involves an implicit conversion. But it's not clear why Clang treats them differently.

From my point of view, GCC and Clang both have different bugs with variadic template deduction, while MSVC does the right thing in both cases. But it's hard to make an argument based on the standard text that this is unambiguously the case.

Comment: I am not sure if your arguments are right here: First, `struct S` supplies a templated constructor, which means that you can construct S from ANY type (you can also give callFunc2 a float, see here: https://godbolt.org/z/Tbv69zz8v), but apparently gcc and clang don't allow the implicit conversion, i.e. call to this constructor. In my opinion, this code should compile on all compilers, unless there is a rule that prohibits the call to this constructor.

Comment: Secondly, I read the paragraph you mentioned as an extension, meaning that you can add additional template arguments, it doesn't mean that the compiler is allowed to deduce the type you actually specified. I would be really surprised if this is the case. If you specify for example `S<int>`, then the first type in `Args...` must be `int`, but the compiler can add additional template arguments if they are needed to match the given function arguments.

Comment: @kamshi I'm afraid I don't understand you. Your example fails to compile on GCC and Clang just like mine does, and you said that in your opinion, it should compile. So it sounds like you agree with my conclusion that MSVC is correct. This also means the code in the question should compile.

Comment: In your example, an object is implicitly converted to another object by calling the templated constructor you supplied. If you remove the constructor, this conversion is not possible and all compilers fail to compile. My code uses function pointers instead. You can also remove the second argument (the `Args&&`), it doesn't matter for the code and doesn't change the problem, I just copied it from my code base. Like I mentioned earlier above, I also learned that apparently function pointers don't care about cv-qualifiers, which is why my code should compile with all compilers.

Comment: @kamshi But it's not really that "function pointers don't care about cv-qualifiers". It's that top-level cv-qualifiers of parameters are always *stripped* when forming the function type. That means that if deduction is done, it deduces the cv-unqualified type. Then, GCC complains about the mismatch between the deduced type and the specified type.

Comment: @kamshi Now, I did say that I think GCC is wrong for the code in the question. I believe it should compile. So I'm still not sure what you disagree with me about. Maybe you're saying that Clang is right in both cases (since Clang accepts the code in the question but rejects my example where an implicit conversion is allowed). If that's what you meant, you should have said it more clearly. But I disagree because I don't understand why, in my case where an implicit conversion is required, this makes the code ill-formed. (1/2)

Comment: @kamshi I agree with your comment that the compiler shouldn't be allowed to re-deduce template arguments that you already specified, which is why, in my opinion, the code in the question should compile, my example should compile, *and* your second example (the godbolt link you posted 16 minutes ago) should also compile. And it surprises me that MSVC is right in all cases. (2/2)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243459/discussion-between-kamshi-and-brian-bi).